# ListBox margin is not the same in Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, windows-8, listbox

I have styled an WPF ListBox. I'm developing under Windows 8. After setup the style to be as follows (see image), when I test the application in Windows 7, the margin is not the same. As you can see in the imagen the separation between nodes is 1px in Windows 8, but 0 px in Windows 7.

[image]

Do you know why is this, and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see if the W7 listbox is considering the border you are setting?

Comment: I have the same problem, the extra margin space doesn't appear in snoop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually managed to get rid of it myself, it looks like it's ListViewItem style that's being changed by Windows8, adding a style to the local resources of the ListView has worked for me.

```
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: This works great.  It appears that only Padding and BorderThickness are needed to resolve it for me.

Answer (score -1):

The default ListBoxItem contains a border. The ListBoxItem also specifies a padding which is inherited by this Border. Its the Padding DP that needs to be set like what Andy mentioned.