# Padding added to elements on Window 8.1-10 but not Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-7-x64

I am currently working on Visual Studio extension displaying a hierarchy of items via a ListView. The WPF ListView contains items styled to appear as if they were part of a tree. They are also styled to reduce their padding, border thickness and margin to 0.

These items can be collapsed or expanded to hide their assigned children. The collapse and expand behaviours basically consist of adding/removing the items off the ListView and changing the state of the Expander element.The scrollbar appears as needed if the amount of items is too big to be contained in the window.

Wanted selection behaviour

[image]

I do get the wanted behaviour most of the time. However, from times to times, all the items change their view to appear like this:

Random behaviour occurring randomly

[image]

The problem repeats consistently when the scrollbar appears or disappears but also occurs without any change in the state of the scrollbar. I tried on VS2015Enterprise and VS2017 Enterprise/Professional and the problem only occurs on Windows 8.1/10. It works fine on Windows 7.

Would you have any ideas as to what might cause this added padding/margin/border?

(I already watched solution of different base style and adding the default style for the used elements did not help).

EDIT: Here is the style used for the items / treeview:

```
<!-- Tree style -->

<Style x:Key="{x:Type custom:IssuesTreeViewInternal}" TargetType="{x:Type custom:IssuesTreeViewInternal}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:IssuesTreeViewInternal}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="_tv_scrollviewer_" Focusable="False" CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- ExpandCollapseToggleStyle style -->

<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Width="15" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Collapsed">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Expanded">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,1,1,2" Data="M 4.5 0.5 L 8.5 4.5 L 4.5 8.5 Z" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.StartPageTextDateBrushKey}}" />
                    <Path x:Name="Expanded" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,0,1,2" Data="M 9.5 0.5 L 9.5 5.5 L 4.5 5.5 Z" Visibility="Hidden" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.StartPageTextDateBrushKey}}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.StartPageTextDateBrushKey}}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Collapsed" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.ScrollBarArrowGlyphPressedBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Expanded" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.ScrollBarArrowGlyphPressedBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Expanded" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.ScrollBarArrowGlyphPressedBrushKey}}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Collapsed" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.StartPageTextDateBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Expanded" Value="Transparent" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- TreeViewItemFocusVisual style -->

<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.SystemHighlightBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- IssuesTreeViewItem style -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type custom:IssuesTreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type custom:IssuesTreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.ToolboxContentTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />   <!-- No need to focus on it. We can have focus on the parent ListViewItem instead. -->
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" /> <!-- 0 border thickness makes sure clicking on the IssuesTreeViewItem is registered everywhere, even in the border area. -->
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Content.Tooltip}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:IssuesTreeViewItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <converters:LeftMarginMultiplierConverter x:Key="LeftMarginMultiplier" DefaultLength="19" />
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border Name="Border" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LeftMarginMultiplier}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" 
                                      Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                      ClickMode="Press" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" 
                                      Command="{Binding Path=ToggleButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" 
                                          Grid.Column="1" 
                                          Content="{Binding Content}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasChildren" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Expander" 
                                Property="Visibility" 
                                Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                                Property="Background" 
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PassiveHighlightBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                                Property="BorderBrush" 
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PassiveHighlightBrush}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" 
                                       Value="False" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Content.IsSuppressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                       Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TextViewItemForegroundColorConverter}}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.SystemHighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.SystemHighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.SystemHighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

We use the TreeView Style this way in the XAML bit of the VS Extension:

```
<local:IssuesTreeViewInternal 
            x:Name="issuesTreeInternal" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
            VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            DataContext="{Binding IssuesTreeViewInternalViewModel}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IssuesTreeItems}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            behaviours:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding SelectedNames}" 
            x:FieldModifier="internal">
            <local:IssuesTreeViewInternal.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
                </Style>
            </local:IssuesTreeViewInternal.ItemContainerStyle>
        </local:IssuesTreeViewInternal>
```

The IssueTreeViewInternal is a class inheriting from ListView.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to also post the style you use for the items / treeview and how you use the treeview in your xaml view

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am sorry it was not done at first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Some spacing was added in Windows 10

this SO answer fixed it :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15618991/4117068

This is what I did

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```